# Страшный зверь для новичка: EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

И вновь случается неизвестное непотребство. Решаю задачу на контесте - он крестится и говорит мне, что это

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "14de642e-f70f-42c7-a3f3-ed7fa87b1df6", line 5, in <module>
    s = input()   
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Перерыл всю программу - на IDLE все работает, контест не пашет ни в какую.

Текст задачи:   По каналу связи передается последовательность положительных целых чисел, все числа не превышают 1000, их количество заранее неизвестно. Каждое число передается отдельно. Признаком конца передаваемой последовательности является число 0. После числа 0 передается контрольное значение – наибольшее число R, удовлетворяющее следующим условиям: 1) R – произведение двух различных переданных элементов последовательности («различные» означает, что не рассматриваются квадраты переданных чисел, произведения раз-личных, но равных по величине элементов допускаются); 2) R делится на 6 Если в последовательности нет такой пары чисел, то контрольное значение считается равным -1. Напишите эффективную программу, которая получает последовательность чисел и следующие за ней признак конца и контрольное значение, а также проверяет правильность контрольного значения.

```py
s = str()
c = 0
max2 = max3 = 0
while s != '0':
    s = int(input())
    if s == 0:
        break
    if s > max3 and s % 3 == 0:
        if max3 > max2 and max3 % 2 == 0:
            max2 = max3
        max3 = s
    elif s > max2 and s % 2 == 0:
        max2 = s
    c += 1
r = int(input())
if (max2 == 0 or max3 == 0) and r == -1:
    print('Recived ' + str(c) + ' numbers', 'Recived reference value: ' + str(r), 'Calculated reference value: ' + str(-1), 'Control passed', sep = '\n')
elif r == (max2*max3):
    print('Recived ' + str(c) + ' numbers', 'Recived reference value: ' + str(r), 'Calculated reference value: ' + str(r), 'Control passed', sep = '\n')
elif r != (max2*max3):
    print('Recived ' + str(c) + ' numbers', 'Recived reference value: ' + str(r), 'Calculated reference value: ' + str(max2*max3), 'Control failed', sep = '\n')
elif (max2 == 0 or max3 == 0) and r != -1:
    print('Recived ' + str(c) + ' numbers', 'Recived reference value: ' + str(r), 'Calculated reference value: ' + str(-1), 'Control failed', sep = '\n')
```

Comment: Вы сохранили код, как бы странно это не звучало? В ошибке упоминается инструкция `s = input()`, но её нет в Вашем коде. И какой-то больно уж странный файл у Вас.

Comment: во время написания вопроса немного изменил код, изначально было:   
```
s = input()   
if s == '0':   
    break   
s = int(s)   
```
Мне кажется, это не слишком питонично, не так ли?

Comment: В таком случае приведите актуальную ошибку, пожалуйста. Это можно сделать, нажав кнопку править под вопросом.

Comment: @nomnoms12
Видимо, проблема была с самим контестом, сейчас их сайт упал, после перезагрузки - проблема исчезла

Comment: Код может и отработает без ошибок времени выполнения, но решение ошибочное. Проверьте на последовательности `1, 6, 0, 6`.

Comment: @extrn, я уже довел программу до ума, сейчас все тесты проходит без ошибок, могу скинуть решение.

Comment: Отлично! Выкладывать или нет - дело ваше, но я бы не стал. Это все-таки олимпиадная задача, незачем упрощать жизнь лентяям :)

Comment: @extrn, понял вас, а лентяи пусть тратят время в поисках ошибки - авось чему научатся :)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была на самом сайте контеста, после его падения и восстановления - все вылечилось.